# How to drag back div to first position when it drags to out of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I have a draggable div in jQuery that can be dragged from its handle. I need to let it revert to its original position when dragged off screen.

html:

```
<div class="mcwindow">
    <div class="wm"></div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".mcwindow" ).resizable();
    $( ".mcwindow" ).draggable({ handle: ".wm" });
    $( "div, p" ).disableSelection();
});
```

css:

```
.mcwindow{
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
border: 4px solid #80d0ff;
border-top:0px;
}

.wm{
background: #80d0ff;
width:100%;
height:30px;
}
```

You can also see the code I have so far here http://jsfiddle.net/mzage/n0gLjs9q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move a div back to its start position if it is dragged out of bounds, you can perform the following. It checks on drag stop. Other events are drag and start:

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

**HTML**

```
<div class="mcwindow">
<div class="wm"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mcwindow{
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
border: 4px solid #80d0ff;
border-top:0px;
background: white;
border-radius: 5px;
width:200px;
height:100px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}

.wm{
background: #80d0ff;
width:100%;
height:30px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var $mcWindow = $('.mcwindow');
$mcWindow.resizable();
$mcWindow.draggable({ handle: ".wm" });
$('div, p').disableSelection();

var docWidth = $(document).width();
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var s = { left: $mcWindow.css('left'), top: $mcWindow.css('top')};
$mcWindow.draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {

        if (ui.position.left < 0) {
            $(this).css({ 'left': 0 });
        }
        if (ui.position.left > docWidth-$(this).width()) {
            $(this).css({ 'left': docWidth-$(this).width()-10 });
        }
        if (ui.position.top < 0) {
            $(this).css({ 'top': 0 });
        }
        if (ui.position.top > docHeight-$(this).height()) {
            $(this).css({ 'top': docHeight-$(this).height()-10 });
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzage/n0gLjs9q/3/